# Errors when trying to send a request

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to test to see if I can send a request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch` in google spreadsheets. Here is my code:

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function myOnEdit(){
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google.com/');
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

When I test the function `createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger` it shows a prompt box saying `authorization required` and when i click the review permissions button and sign in it says `This app isn't verified`. I am also not sure how to use installable triggers so that my custom onEdit works.

I would appreciate any working examples as I have been trying a long time to get this to work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of scripts:

- [Bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
- [Standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

Bound scripts can call a few methods that standalone scripts cannot:

- getActiveSpreadsheet(), getActiveDocument(), and getActiveForm() allow bound scripts to refer to their parent file without referring to the file's ID.
- getUi lets bound scripts access the user interface for their parent file to add custom menus, dialogs, and sidebars.
- In Google Sheets, getActiveSheet(), getActiveRange(), and getActiveCell() let the script determine the user's current sheet, selected range of cells, or selected individual cell. setActiveSheet(sheet) and setActiveRange(range) let the script change those selections.

You can also create a installable trigger in bound scripts manually:
[The official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) :

To manually create an installable trigger through a dialog in the script editor, follow these steps:

- From the script editor, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
- Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
- Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger.
- Under Events, select either Time-driven or the Google App that the script is bound to (for example, From spreadsheet).
- Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (for example, an Hour timer that runs Every hour or an On open trigger).
- Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you will be contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
- Click Save.

To programmatically craft a installable trigger:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forSpreadsheet(String)

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
.forSpreadsheet('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
.onEdit()
.create();
```

**SUMMARY:** To create this trigger from a standalone script, simply replace `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` with a call to `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`. ID is the key of your spreadsheet:. For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is "abc1234567".

Code:

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet('ID')
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function myOnEdit(){
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google.com/');
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: I tried to create an  installable trigger using the steps you provided and I was prompted a message saying i need to review my permissions and then it said and error message saying `This app isn't verified`

Comment: @Mr. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-intro/img/5b2492de946a3d6e.png

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, now everything works. that is the working solution to my error problem i guess you can edit your answer and ill mark it as solved